# How to tab-focus paper-button polymer?

Tags: html, polymer, material-design, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I have a form with several input fields and checkbox. I can shift focus through the input fields and checkboxes. But the "SAVE" paper-button at the page wont get focus at all. User needs to use a mouse to click the paper-button.

How to make paper-button focusable?

Answer (score 0):

Tabbing seems to work fine for me with the following code:

```
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>

  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/">
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html">
</head>

<body>

  <dom-module id="element-name">
    <template>
        <paper-input label="input 1"></paper-input> 
        <paper-input label="input 2"></paper-input> 
        <paper-input label="input 3"></paper-input> 
        <paper-input label="input 4"></paper-input> 
        <paper-input label="input 5"></paper-input>
        <paper-checkbox>Checkbox</paper-checkbox>
        <paper-button>Button</paper-button>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: "element-name"
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <element-name></element-name>
</body>

</html>
```

Can you provide some code showing your problem?